# Footnotes inline and without indentation

Tags: footnotes

One can have multiple footnotes on the same line, using

```
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
```

but it produces extra space between numbers and respective notes (as the figure below shows). I'd like to remove this space. If someone could help me, I'd be grateful. Anyway, thank you for your attention!

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book} 
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}

\begin{document}

\ \vfill

First unknown word\footnote{The first note.}. 
Second one\footnote{The second one}. 
Third one\footnote{The third one.}.

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

Comment: Please provide code in the form of a minimal document we can compile to see the problem. This is much more useful than a fragment of code.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Try `\footglue=0.2em plus.3em minus.3em` in your preamble, for example

Comment: Thank you for your hint, but it doesn't work for me. It only reduces the space between the end of a note and the number of the following note. I'd like to reduce the space between a note and its number. I recognize my question causes this doubt. So I'll edit it. I guess we have three parameters in your code. Could you explain which each one of them is related with, please?

Comment: Then `\footglue` won't help (I misunderstood what you wanted). Try this in the preamble, instead: `\makeatletter\long\def\@makefntext#1{\leavevmode\@makefnmark\nobreak\hskip.1em\relax#1}\makeatother`, where the dimension of `\hskip` can be changed to your liking (default is .5em, from the [package documentation](http://mirror.pregi.net/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/footmisc/footmisc.pdf))

Comment: Perfect! It is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you, @Troy! Would you like to answer or you'd prefer I to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant code from the [`footmisc` package documentation](http://mirror.pregi.net/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/footmisc/footmisc.pdf) can be found in Section 5.3 Support code for paragraph footnotes, which is as follows:

```
% Taken from package documentation, Sect 5.3
\long\def\@makefntext#1{\leavevmode
    \@makefnmark\nobreak
    \hskip.5em\relax#1%
}
```

The command `\@makefntext` prints out the footnote number (`\@makefnmark`) + the actual footnote itself (taken as an argument `#1`).
In between the footnote mark and the footnote text, there is a horizontal spacing of `\hskip.5em`, which is the spacing that you want to change.

**A full MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book} 
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@makefntext#1{\leavevmode
    \@makefnmark\nobreak
    \hskip.1em\relax#1% <----------- change the dimension here
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    First unknown word\footnote{The first note.}. 
    Second one\footnote{The second one}. 
    Third one\footnote{The third one.}.
\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Note the spacing marked out by the arrows -- that is the spacing affected by `\hskip<dim>` from the original code.